# Compiling java project using terminal

Tags: java, linux, compilation, terminal

There is a project called javachallenge that contains four folders inside it: bin, ee, server ,src.

this projects need server/server.jar for external library and it's main method is inside src/javachallenge/client/Connector.java

how can i run this project using terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure the JDK binaries are on your PATH, and then you call `javac` (The java compiler).

Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html for information on how to use the java compiler.

After you compiled all classes, you call `java -cp /path/to/compiled/classes:server/server.jar javachallenge.client.Connector` (assuming the class is in the `javachallenge.client` package. The `-cp` option tells the Java virtual machine where to look for classes, so you have to include both the directory with classes you compiled before, and the external library these classes depend on.

You can call both `java` and `javac` with no arguments to get a list of available options if you get stuck.